# How to write Integration Test for Rest Post Api MultiPart using ClientBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am trying to write Integration test for Post api for Multipart upload but unable to so.
My cod looks like this..
My controller method looks like below.

```
create(@RequestPart("createBean") CreateBean bean,
       @RequestPart("infoBean") InfoBean infobean,
       @RequestPart(value="file" required=false) List<MultiPartFile> file){}
```

For integration test of this Post Api I am trying to do the following.

```
ClientBuilder.newClient().target(LocalHost).request().post(Entity.entity(bean),MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```

But getting error.
How can I pass bean , infobean and file as part of single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write integration test for Multipart you can just use FormDataMultipart.

Just pass the bean with name value pair.

formDataMultipart.field("createBean", bean, Media type.Json)

and just pass this as Entity.entity(formDataMultipart)